# HTML Form with PHPmail - script does not process form

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to send the contents of a form using PHPmail. When I submit the form, it goes to a blank page - the PHP script as a webpage.

I have tried to re-use the code generated by the code generator file that comes in the PHPMailer documentation but to no avail.

Form code extract:

```
<form method="post" action="referralengine.php" id="myForm" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="field1" name="field1" placeholder="Enter data" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field2">Field 2</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="field2" name="field2" rows="4" placeholder="Enter data" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="field3">Field 3</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="field2" name="field2" rows="4" placeholder="Enter data" ></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="newupload">Upload file</label>
        <input type="file" id="newupload" name="newupload" class="input-file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

The PHP is as follows:

```
<?php
    require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $field1= Trim(stripslashes($_POST['field1']));
    $field2= Trim(stripslashes($_POST['field2']));
    $field3= Trim(stripslashes($_POST['field3']));

    // Email body text
    $content .= "Item 1: " .$field1 ."\n";
    $content .= "Item 2: " .$field2 ."\n";
    $content .= "Item 3: " .$field3 ."\n";

    $results_messages = array();

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    $mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';

    $mail->From = "fromAddress@mail.com";
    $mail->FromName = "Some name";
    $mail->addAddress("toAddress@mail.com");
    $mail->Subject = "PHPMailer test using SENDMAIL";
    $body = $content;
    $mail->WordWrap = 78;
    $mail->addAttachment($_FILES['newupload']['tmp_name']);

    try {
        $mail->send();
        $results_messages[] = "Message has been sent using SENDMAIL";
    }
    catch (phpmailerException $e) {
        throw new phpmailerAppException('Unable to send to: ' . $to. ': '.$e->getMessage());
    }
    catch (phpmailerAppException $e) {
        $results_messages[] = $e->errorMessage();
    }

    if (count($results_messages) > 0) {
        echo "<h2>Run results</h2>\n";
        echo "<ul>\n";
        foreach ($results_messages as $result) {
            echo "<li>$result</li>\n";
        }
        echo "</ul>\n";
    }

?>
```

Any suggestions welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably, there is some error. Enable error reporting in php and you'll see the error message on the page which is blank now.

Comment: Sometimes on linux servers phpmailer comes with an smtp.php file. that file sometimes is being included in upper case in the phpmailer.php file what results in an error because of the case difference

Comment: @ITroubs, that's obsolete - you should only be loading the autoloader now.

Comment: @Synchro that still doesn't change the fact, that case sensitivity can mess up a bit and in earlier versions ist really messed up stuff.

Comment: The autoloader already forces to lower case, and why would you be using an earlier version?